# Problem understanding domain of circular relation

Tags: relations

I came across an exercise in a book which introduces the circular relation as:

> $C$ is a relation from $R \to R$ such that $(x,y) \in C$ means $x^2+y^2 = 1$.

It then says that the domain of $C$ is $R$.

However, as I understand things, the domain can only be the set of all $x$ that satisfy the relation. For example, the number 5 will never be in the domain of $C$, no matter what $y$ we choose. What is going on here? Is the book in error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a more general context than that of functions - a *relation* need not be "defined" everywhere on the domain. A relation $R$ between sets $X$ and $Y$ (also sometimes phrased as "from $X$ to $Y$") is just a subset $R\subseteq X\times Y$. The set $X$ is, by definition, the domain of $R$. [Here's the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_relation#Formal_definition).

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm embarrassed, to say the least, having misunderstood the very definition. :P

Comment: Glad I could help. And happens to all of us sometimes :)